# What is the reliable method of time measurement in a cpu-throttling system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu, clock, cpu-architecture

Modern CPUs alter the CPU frequency on core-by-core basis.  I have done my research and I found a lot of people talking about clocks being skewed because of this.  What I have not found was a good method for dealing with the clock-skew.  What is the proper method of doing it (preferably in Linux)?

Bonus question:  how does any of this change if the system is running inside of a VM?

Answer (score 1):

`clock_gettime()` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` shouldn't see clock skew. Indeed, the Linux manpage for `clock_gettime()` only documents `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` and `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` as being affected by clock skew.

Answer (score 0):

Newer chipsets incorporate a High Precision Event Timer ([**HPET**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer)) which addresses this issue.  If your OS is HPET-aware (e.g. Windows 7, Linux 2.6.27) the critical kernel-mode timing functions should not have a skew problem.